# Как вывести данные из JSON?

Tags: python, json

Есть JSON с данными о пользователях.

```
{
  "profiles":[{
    "id": 123123,
    "first_name": "Vasya",
    "last_name": "Pupkin"
  },{
    "id": 345345,
    "first_name": "Sasha",
    "last_name": "Oreshkin"
  },{
    "id": 678900,
    "first_name": "Pasha",
    "last_name": "Markin"
  }]
}
```

Хочу вывести все имена в одну строку через запятую,

```
users = usersJson['profiles'][0]['first_name']
print(users)

>>> Vasya
```

но получается вывести только одно имя, а не все.

Если уберу ноль, то вот что:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://ideone.com/dy57Dd

```
import json

data = json.loads('''{
  "profiles":[{
    "id": 123123,
    "first_name": "Vasya",
    "last_name": "Pupkin"
  },{
    "id": 345345,
    "first_name": "Sasha",
    "last_name": "Oreshkin"
  },{
    "id": 678900,
    "first_name": "Pasha",
    "last_name": "Markin"
  }]
}''')

res = [p['first_name'] for p in data['profiles']]

print(res)
```

```
['Vasya', 'Sasha', 'Pasha']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print(*[ n['first_name'] for n in usersJson['profiles'] ], sep=", ")
Vasya, Sasha, Pasha
```